# upload or auto setup feature photo by user avatar

Tags: post-thumbnails, avatar

I want user avatar image is set as a feature image, If there is no featured image.

I am trying to do like this.

```
function auto_featured_image() {
global $post;

if (!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
    //$attached_avatar = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ));
    $attached_avatar = get_avatar(1);

  if ($attached_image) { // set feature image as the 1st image on post.
          foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
               set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
          }
  }/*elseif($attached_avatar){ // set feature image as the avatar image.
            foreach ($attached_avatar as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
            }

  }*/
 }
}
 // Use it temporary to generate all featured images
add_action('the_post', 'auto_featured_image');
// Used for new posts
add_action('save_post', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
```

set feature image as the 1st image on post works fine. but set avatar as feature image is not working.

How can I make it work?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general avatars can not be a replacement to attachments unless you have a pluging which forces all avatars to be uploaded via the wordpress upload process to the site (or in other words, be included in the media library). Avatars can be any URL while attachments have an id in your DB. Therefor your attempt to treat the avatar as an attachment can not succeed.

The only way to make it work is if you will first fetch the avatar image from whatever service it is located on, and create an attachment out of it. Then you can treat it in the way your code implies you intended to do.

Comment: I use a plugin and all avatars saved in my DB (user-meta). the data looks like this...
umeta_id user_id meta_key meta_value
865039 1 simple_local_avatar a:14:{s:4:"full";s:70:"http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/my_avatar.gif"... etc..

is there anyway to make it with this avatar in user-meta?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: and I use simple local avatar plugin.

Comment: then it is plugin specific and you need to make attachments out of the avatar images if the plugin doesn't do it. Maybe you should ask the plugin author.

Comment: do you mean when you upload your avatar, it needs to be stored in wp-post and wp-post-meta tables as well? not only user-meta talbe?  am I understanding?

Comment: yes, like any attachment when it is uploaded to the server. But you don't need to write to the DB yourself, just use an API like `wp_insert_attachment` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment